# Limitar quantidade de caracteres por linha jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tenho alguns campos `textarea` e eu quero **limitar a quantidade de caracteres por linha** usando jQuery.

Eu não tenho código para tratar ainda Laerte, eu faço a inserção no banco de dados com o php e exibo no html com nl2br do php para quebrar a linha. 
Preciso limitar e não sei como fazer, quando o usuário digita uma quantidade de caracteres que ultrapassa a largura da div o texto continua para fora da div pois não teve uma quebra de linha. Não estou no com problema no textarea pessoal, estou na hora de puxar do banco, eu não tenho problemas com a quantidade de caracteres e sim com a quantidade de caracteres sem dar um espaço ficando uma palavra imensa. –

Comment: define um maxlength no textarea e coloca um max-width e maxheight no css

Comment: Já tentei, estoura  a div e tem alguns navegadores que não obedecem o comando do maxlenght.

Comment: Pode adicionar o código na pergunta?

Comment: Você quer fazer um word wrap?

Comment: que navegador você testou ? http://caniuse.com/#feat=maxlength

Comment: Eu não tenho código para tratar ainda Laerte, eu faço a inserção no banco de dados com o php e exibo no html com nl2br do php ára quebrar a linha.
Preciso limitar e não sei como fazer, quando o usuário digita uma quantidade de caracteres que ultrapassa a largura da div o texto continua para fora da div pois não teve uma quebra de linha.

Não estou no com problema no textarea pessoal, estou na hora de puxar do banco, eu não tenho problemas com a quantidade de caracteres e sim com a quantidade de caracteres sem dar um espaço ficando uma palavra imensa.

Comment: Talvez você possa tratar isso diretamente no html usando a propriedade wrap="on" no seu text area exemplo no link https://jsfiddle.net/r63sfc4o/

Answer (score 2):

Tente assim:

```css
textarea {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 100px;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 100px;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea maxlength="255"></textarea>
```